# UART Transmissions from MSPM0G3507 not working when connect to STM32G474, but working when have Jlink connected in parallel

Tags: embedded, stm32, mcu

I am using two mcus, they are MSPM0G3507 from TI, and STM32G474 from ST and I want the stm32 mcu to command the msp mcu via uart. I am now transmitting a byte from stm32 using interrupt, and if that byte is correct the msp mcu would send a byte back to stm32 mcu using DMA.
The problem is the transmission from stm32 to msp is ok, but the transmission from msp to stm32 not working, the uart Rx handler function in the stm32 mcu was not called, the stm32 mcu received nothing (using a oscilloscope I did not see any logic signal).
A weird thing happens that when I connect the Tx pin and GND pin of the msp mcu to a Jlink-OB V2 in  parallel with stm32 mcu, and only then the transmission from msp to stm32 started working, the byte the stm32 mcu received was correct and I can see the logic signals on the oscilloscope also the byte that my PC received using that Jlink was correct too. When I connect Jlink to msp but not connect that Jlink to my PC the transmision from msp to stm32 works just fine.
Does anyone has any idea about this? Please let me know.

For the stm32 mcu: Rx using DMA. Tx using interrupt.
for the msp mcu: Rx and Tx using DMA.
mu configs here [myconfig](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjiwRll09HuPgcIvriceUYfoRm1Pmg?e=rg3mPK)

I tried the uart example code (uart transmission using DMA) from TI for the transmission from msp to stm32 but it is still not working, it worked only when a Jlink-OB V2 connected in parallel like I said.

Comment: What signals do you have connected between the two boards (when the J-Link is not part of the system)?

Comment: Please don't connect things to places that are not designed for that. You can do some electrical damage. UART is a one-to-one connection. If something goes wrong there, you may damage devices (even with a software bug, if you are unlucky). Next, you have UART Tx on one of MCUs not working as expected. But does it work with a hello world UART program? (just send 1 byte over and over). And with DMA? Have you tried increasing time between communications to see if that changes behavior? Have you checked MSP UART flags when the supposed transmission doesn't happen? There could be some error flag.

Comment: @pmacfarlane The two boards have the same ADC signals, I am now using the stm32 to check the ADC signals that go to the msp.

Comment: @Ilya It worked with the J-link, I tested the UART signal by sending it to the J-link which connected with my PC, and read the value of the byte I sent using a program called "serial oscilloscope". I do not really understand what you wanted to say "increasing the time between communications", can you tell me more specifically? I am now re-sending the byte every time that the UART sending flag is true in the UART interrupt handler function which means every time the msp completes sending 1 byte, But as I said the msp not sending any byte so that flag is never true.

Comment: @Ilya I will try checking the error flags as soon as I can go back to my lab and give you the information, thank you